# How to build and make my war artifact with some profile properties, like maven properties profiles in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In maven there is a plug in that allows you to replace place holders with some concrete value. I am talking about

```
<profiles>

 <id>aghanayem</id>
       <properties>
          <profile>somepropfile</profile>
          </properties>
   </profile>
```

When I build and make the project with idea profiles are ignored

How can I make idea build my project with a specific profile ?

Comment: How do you build with Intellij? Do you trigger the Maven goal?

Comment: No, I configure the build from project structure -> Artifacts, so I can deploy on Tomcat from idea.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. If you use Maven, **use Maven**. Having a multitude of different build tools is pointless and has very high maintenance costs. Use the Maven Tomcat plugin to deploy your app on an embedded Tomcat, and run the goal from Intellij. This also has the benefit of working without Intellij, or any IDE for that matter.

Comment: If I deploy throw maven I am then loosing some of IDEA features, like deploy by only clicking the green play button, have the logs show in front of me with the need to add them manually ... and so on !